# Firebug Lite doesn't open in Safari on iPhone with iOS 6.1

Tags: javascript, debugging, firebug, firebug-lite

I don't get Firebug Lite running. Neither the bookmark nor the inclusion of the script is opening Firebug Lite in Safari on a iPhone with iOS 6. Nothing happens.

How do I get it running?

Comment: I tried the bookmarklet with iOS 6.1.2 and it just works fine. Any error messages? Be sure that JavaScript is enabled. If you own a mac with Safari 6 you can also use Safari to [debug safari or phonegap on iOS Devices](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/DebuggingSafarioniPhoneContent/DebuggingSafarioniPhoneContent.html). Maybe this works on Windows.

Comment: There is no error. JavaScript is enabled. I have a Mac but not here. I'll upgrade to iOS 6.1.2. Perhaps this makes a difference ...

Comment: Perhaps it is the content, but Firebug Lite is only opened in IE9 if I press F12 ... The funny thing is that the JS code never appears in the HTML code within Firebug.

Comment: Is it a local page you want to analyze or a public available page?

Comment: It's on a server - so basically everyone who knows the url can access it. But in the meantime I figured out where my problem is (without Firebug Lite).

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this, and it works for me.

http://osxdaily.com/2011/12/02/run-firebug-on-ipad-or-iphone/

1. Bookmark a web page from Safari in iOS and rename the bookmark to “Firebug”
2. Select & copy the JavaScript text block below

   javascript:(function(F,i,r,e,b,u,g,L,I,T,E){if(F.getElementById(b))return;E=F[i+'NS']&&F.documentElement.namespaceURI;E=E?Fi+'S':Fi;Er;Er;Er;(Fe[0]||Fe[0]).appendChild(E);E=new%20Image;Er;})(document,'createElement','setAttribute','getElementsByTagName','FirebugLite','4','firebug-lite.js','releases/lite/latest/skin/xp/sprite.png','http://web.archive.org/web/20171023043748/https://getfirebug.com/','#startOpened');
3. Now edit the Firebug bookmark you made, and remove the URL, replacing it with the javascript you just copied
4. Tap on “Done” and then hit the bookmarklet to activate Firebug Lite on the iPad

Answer (score -1):

This ine worked fine on Safari on 6.1.2 http://thesimplesynthesis.com/post/firebug-on-iphone-ipad-android-and-other-devices/